# Twilio send sms return null

Tags: .net, vb.net, twilio

When I try to use twilio API in vb.net, the result returns null.

```
    Imports Twilio
    Imports System

    Protected Sub btnCall_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCall.Click
        SendSMS()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub SendSMS()
        Try
            Dim client As TwilioRestClient = New TwilioRestClient(AccountSId, AuthToken)
            Dim result = client.SendMessage("***", "***", "Hello World", "")
            Response.Write(result.Status)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write("Error")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

The from number is a twilio number, and to number is a US phone number. The client has connected. But the "result" returns null. And there is nothing on twilio dashboard. The result.status throw to exception because result is null. I use vs 2010 and twilio package is installed from nuget, version 3.6.27. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

Try checking the [RestException](https://www.twilio.com/docs/csharp/install#exceptions) property on your result:

```
Dim result = client.SendMessage("***", "***", "Hello World", "")
If (result.RestException IsNot Nothing) Then
     Console.Writeline(result.RestException.Message)
End If
```

Hope that helps.